# SQL Server Inserting Wrong Values with VBScript

Tags: sql-server, csv, vbscript

I have a script that uploads items from a CSV. There are 3 columns to the CSV and 3 columns in the database.

Code (nvarchar 255)
name (nvarchar 255)
price (money)

The script is the following

```
' --- Connect to File.CSV
csvConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
&Server.MapPath("..\upload") &";Extended 
Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';"
Set connCSV = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connCSV.Open csvConnStr


set csvCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
csvCmd.ActiveConnection = connCSV
csvCmd.CommandType = 1
csvCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM upload.csv"
set rsCsv = csvCmd.Execute

csvCode= rsCsv.fields.item(0)
csvName= rsCsv.fields.item(1)
csvPrice = rsCsv.fields.item(2)
```

Note - I have ommited the loop through the csv as do not feel it is a cause of my problem but can include upon request.

```
set insertCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
insertCmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
insertCmd.CommandType = 1
insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProducts (code, name, price) VALUES (?,?,?)"
insertCmd.Parameters.append(
insertCmd.CreateParameter("@code",200,1,255,csvCode))
insertCmd.Parameters.append(
insertCmd.CreateParameter("@name",200,1,255,csvName))
insertCmd.Parameters.append(
insertCmd.CreateParameter("@price", 6, 1, , csvPrice))
insertCmd.Execute
```

My CSV has the following structure

```
Item Code, Item Name, Item Price
00001, First Item, 100
00002, Second Item, 100
```

The script will insert fine except in the scenario that the Item Code begins with the character 'F'.

Example,

```
Item Code, Item Name, Item Price
F0445, Item X, 200
```

Will insert a record but in the database will have the Code = 445

This is only with F, so codes such as

```
Item Code, Item Name, Item Price
G0445, Item Y, 200
FG0445, Item X, 200
```

Will insert quite alright. Is F a special character in VBScript? How come it won't insert the whole code?

Comment: Be calm and try to find the cause one by one.

Comment: Do you have single-quotes ' around the varchars in the sql-statement? How does the finished sql statement look like when you run it?

Comment: thanks reds. Hi @Sourcery, I do not have single-quotes around the variables in the sql-statement. I printed out the SQL statement and it is inserting the value as the shrunken code. I added a print after csvCode = rsCsv.fields.item(0) and here csvCode = 0445. The read is removing the first few characters (well, only when beginning with F!)

Comment: Im thinking that F somehow formats the data, so by using single-quotes so the value is 'F0445' should work to add a varchar to the database? so the end sql should be: INSERT INTO tblProducts (code, name, price) VALUES ('F0445','Item X',200), the single-quotes tells sql that it is text inserted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time. You are right in that F is formatting the data. I have the document open in excel and it is assuming that F is a function operator, despite me not defining it! If you would like to post an answer @sourcery i will be happy to accept for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment.

Im thinking that F somehow formats the data, so by using single-quotes so the value is 'F0445' should work to add a varchar to the database? so the end sql should be: INSERT INTO tblProducts (code, name, price) VALUES ('F0445','Item X',200), the single-quotes tells sql that it is text inserted.

Also from your last comment, format the column/cells in Excel to be text.